# How to iterate through a only module's functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code module.py:

```
from module1 import *

def func1:
    ...
def func2:
    ...
...
```

and

```
import module
for name in cases.__dict__.iteritems():
    print name
```

it prints also functions of module1.

I need func1, func2, ...

How to get all functions of imported modules in the module or iterate through functions of **only** module (without imported)?